# Integer Points in plane

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have 5 points in the plane with integer cordinates.Prove that exists 2 points of which we select the mid point of the line of the choosen 2 has integer cordinates.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand the question, but what happens if you chose $(1,1)$ and $(0,0)$ ? It seems to me that the mid point is $(1/2,1/2)$ and thus has not integer coordinates.

Comment: Yes I also got stuck on that.

Comment: Suppose the cordinates are (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) of the point.Suppose we choose for all points even/odd x and even/odd y.We will always have.

Comment: Suppose x1+x2 is odd and y1+y2 is odd.Then one of  the 2 in the sum must be even and the other odd.If we are lucky we will end our problem with the 3rd and the 4th point but if we need to find the 5th point cordinates the others 4 will have all needed parity to combine with the 5-th so that their sum of cordinates divides 2 :)

Comment: Solution:Since the pairs (o,e) (e,o)and  (o,o) (e,e) solve our problem suppose we have have to create the points we have to chose 1 pair from both sets.If we chose the same pair from the set it is over,otherwise if we choose 2 more by Dirihlet we will have 2 pairs in one set which solves our problem?

Comment: Gordon:  If you have five points in the plane with integer coordinates, then there must exist a pair of points such that the midpoint of the segment connecting them has integer coordinates for the reason you cited in your latest comment.  However, the way you stated the problem permits the counterexample cited by @JérémyBlanc.

Comment: yes,sorry my bad

Comment: Now, it is better.

Answer (score 5):

For each of the five points $(a,b)$, consider the value modulo $2$ ($0$ if even and $1$ if odd): $([a],[b])$. There are only four possible values, namely $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$ or $(0,0)$, hence two need to be equal, modulo $2$. This implies that the two points have coordinates of the same parity and thus that the mid point has integer coefficients.